# Filter Map of Map of List

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a HashMap of type:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<MyPojo>>> myMap;
```

`MyPojo` has an element `String domain`.

In some cases this domain can be null.

I want to filter my map so that none of the submap `Map<String, List<MyPojo>>` should have null domain.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  If after filtering the `List<MyPojo>` for some `String` is empty, do you want to remove that mapping?  If yes, then if the `Map<String, List<MyPojo>>` is empty after filtering (and then removing the mapping) do you want _that_ mapping removed too?
Or do you _just_ want the `MyPojo`s which have `null` `domain`s removed from the `List`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opening note: You probably shouldn't be having a `Map<String, Map<String, List<MyPojo>>>` - that's far too convoluted. There should be more written-out types here. Perhaps a `Map<String, Students>` or some such. Your question doesn't make clear what your problem domain is, so all I can say is that your starting type is probably not good code style.

Let's get to your question:

If you mean `filter` as in j.u.Stream's filter, then you can't. The `Map` interface doesn't have a `removeIf`, and the stream/filter stuff isn't about changing existing types, only about making new stuff. Any attempt to modify the underlying map would just get you ConcurrentModificationExceptions.

Here is how to change the map 'in place'

```
var it = myMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
   if (it.next().getValue().values().stream()
     // we now have a stream of lists.
     .anyMatch(
       list -> list.stream().anyMatch(mp -> mp.getDomain() == null))) {
     it.remove();
    }
}
```

You have a nested anyMatch operation here: You want to remove a k/v pair if *any* of the entries in the submap contains a list for which *any* of its entries has a null domain.

Let's see it in action:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

@lombok.Value class MyPojo {
  String domain;
}

class Test { public static void main(String[] args) {
Map<String, Map<String, List<MyPojo>>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("A", Map.of("X", List.of(), "Y", List.of(new MyPojo(null))));
myMap.put("B", Map.of("V", List.of(), "W", List.of(new MyPojo("domain"))));

System.out.println(myMap);

var it = myMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
   if (it.next().getValue().values().stream()
     // we now have a stream of lists.
     .anyMatch(
       list -> list.stream().anyMatch(mp -> mp.getDomain() == null))) {
     it.remove();
    }
}

System.out.println(myMap);

}}
```

Code that produces a new map is not that hard to figure out given the above.

Comment: Thanks. I know the input structure is badly styled, but its out of my control. This use case is inside a if condition which will rarely be true. So instead of transforming the data type I was curious how to do it inline.

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in the comment, it's unclear (to me at least) if you want the mappings to stay in place for empty `List`s or `Map`s after your filtering, but if you don't care about empty `Map`s/`List`s afterwards you can just use:

```java
map.values().stream().flatMap(v -> v.values().stream())
        .forEach(l -> l.removeIf(p -> p.getDomain() == null));
```